# Issue with "undefined" in URL when working with Cloudinary and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend, cloudinary

**I'm currently working on a project using Express.js for the back-end and React for the front-end. The project involves uploading images to Cloudinary, and the Cloudinary URLs are then saved in a MongoDB database. However, I'm encountering an issue where the Cloudinary URL stored in the database contains an "undefined" string at the beginning.**

Problem Description:

Here's the sequence of steps in my project:

Front-end: I select an image to upload, and I correctly obtain the Cloudinary URL for the image using the Cloudinary API.

Back-end (Express.js): I send the Cloudinary URL from the front-end to the server and store it in the MongoDB database.

**However, when I later retrieve the Cloudinary URL from the database, it appears as
"undefined" followed by the actual Cloudinary URL
(e.g:  "undefinedhttp://res.cloudinary.com/...").**
[image]

**Backend:**

```
// Back-end code for handling image upload
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const cloudinary = require('../utils/cloudinary');

//upload

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads' });

// ... (other imports and middleware)

// POST /upload/image
// Upload product images
// Protected route (isAuth middleware checks authentication)

router.post('/image', isAuth, upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.file.path;

    // Upload the image to Cloudinary
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(file);

    // Check if the image was successfully uploaded to Cloudinary
    if (!result || !result.url) {
      return res.status(500).json({ errors: { msg: 'Image upload failed' } });
    }

    // If the image was uploaded successfully, save the Cloudinary URL in the database
    const imagePath = result.url;

    // ... (other code for saving imagePath to MongoDB)

    res.status(200).json({ imagePath });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: { msg: 'Server error' } });
  }
});

// ... (other routes)
```

**Frontend**

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    productName: '',
    description: '',
    basePrice: 0,
    duration: 300,
    category: '',
    image: '',
  });
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState('Choose your image file...');
  const [fileValid, setFileValid] = useState(true);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      props.clearAlerts();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleFormChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Check for empty fields
    if (form.productName === '') {
      return props.setAlert('Product name required!');
    }
    if (form.basePrice.toString() === '0') {
      return props.setAlert('Base price required!');
    }
    if (form.duration.toString() === '0') {
      setForm({ ...form, duration: 300 });
    }
    if (!fileValid) {
      // if selected file is not image/exceeds size limit
      props.setAlert('Image file not valid!', 'error');
    } else {
      if (file === '') {
        // submit without photo
        await props.postAd(form);
        navigate('/');
      } else {
        // with photo
        const imagePath = await uploadImage();
        console.log(imagePath);
        if (imagePath) {
          await props.postAd({ ...form, image: imagePath });
          navigate('/');
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const fileSelected = (e) => {
    let filesize = (e.target.files[0].size / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(3);
    let fileType = e.target.files[0].type.toString();
    let regex = /^image\/(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/;
    // if (fileType !== 'image/jpeg' && fileType !== 'image/png') {
    if (!regex.test(fileType)) {
      props.setAlert('Image must be of type JPEG, PNG or GIF');
      setFile('');
      setFileValid(false);
    } else if (filesize > 3) {
      props.setAlert('Image size must be less than 3 MB', 'error');
      setFile('');
      setFileValid(false);
    } else {
      setFileValid(true);
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
      setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
      console.log(e.target.files[0]);
      
    }
  };




const uploadImage = async () => {
  setUploading(true);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    console.log(file)
    console.log(formData)
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/upload/image`,
        formData,
        { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
      );
      console.log(res.data)
      return res.data.imagePath;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setUploading(false);
      props.setAlert('File upload failed', 'error');
    }
};
```

**Context:**

- The code for handling image uploads to Cloudinary and saving the URL
  to MongoDB appears to be functioning as expected, but the issue
  arises when the URL is retrieved from the database later.
- The imagePath variable is correctly populated with the Cloudinary URL
  before saving it in the database, and there are no issues when
  sending the URL to the front-end after the image upload.

Comment: Can you please share this cloudinary.uploader.upload utility function also for more clarification

Comment: I have added the upload utility.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have under " // ... (other code for saving imagePath to MongoDB)"

Comment: Updated Frontend...

Answer (score 0):

It's likely originates from how you're processing the response on the frontend side after uploading the image. Can you try adding validation like this?

```js
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/upload/image`,
      formData,
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
    );

    if (res.data && typeof res.data.imagePath === 'string') {
      return res.data.imagePath;
    } else {
      return 'Default URL or handle the error';
    }
  }
```